# How to make a PSD plot using `np.fft.fft`?

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I want to make a plot of power spectral density versus frequency for a signal using the `numpy.fft.fft` function. I want to do this so that I can preserve the complex information in the transform and know what I'm doing, as apposed to relying on higher-level functions provided by `numpy` (like the `periodogram` function). I'm following Mathwork's nice page about doing PSD analysis using Matlab's fft function: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html

In this example, I expect the PSD to peak at the frequency I used to construct the signal, which was 100 in this case. I generate the signal using 1000 time points a frequency of 100 inverse time units. I thought that the fft magnitude could be plotted against `[0, nt/2]` and the peaks would show up where there is the most energy in the frequency. When I did this, things went wrong. I expected my PSD to peak at 100.

How can I make a spectral density plot of frequency vs energy contained in that frequency using `np.fft.fft`?

**Edit**

to clarify, in my real problem, I only know that my characteristic frequency is much larger than my sample frequency

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
t = np.arange(1000)
sp = np.fft.fft(np.sin(100 * t * np.pi))
trange = np.linspace(0, t[-1] / 2, t.size)
plt.plot(trange, np.abs(sp) / t.size)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is a sketch I made of the expected output:

[image]

Comment: If using SciPy is an option, check out [`scipy.signal.spectrogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.periodogram.html) and [`scipy.signal.welch`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks but I am looking for a method to explicitly calculate the PSD as a function of frequency using `np.fft.fft`.

Comment: You want to *roll your own* or are you asking us to find a method/function in a library?  Have you looked at the source for PSD implemented in  scipy or matplotlib, they may be adaptable.

Comment: Yeah I want to roll out my own

Comment: Have you looked at the example in the [docstring of `numpy.ftt.fft`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html)?  In particular, look at the use of [`numpy.fft.fftfreq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html) in that example.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yup! I read that before asking my question and ran that code myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your sample frequency? This sequence you are generating can represent a infinite number of continuous time signals according to the sample frequency.
The sample frequency needs to be at least twice the maximum signal frequency, as stated by the Sampling Theorem, so, using fs = 250Hz and using a sine of 10 seconds it becomes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fs = 250
t = np.arange(0, 10, 1/fs)
sp = np.fft.fft(np.sin(2*np.pi * 100 * t))
trange = np.linspace(0, fs, len(t))
plt.plot(trange, np.abs(sp))
plt.show()
```

If you run this you will see a peak at 100Hz as expected.

Comment: Thanks! When I run that I see two equal peaks at 100 and 150. Why is there a peak at 150?

Comment: Also it produces kind of weird behavior when I change the 10 * number of samples variable `fs`. I expected it to produce the same peak at 100 no matter how many samples I take.

Comment: Because the spectrum of a discrete signal is a periodic function with period fs.

Comment: If you increase fs the range of the spectrum will change, since it goes from 0hz to fs Hz, if you decrease it to lower than 200 you get overlap of frequencies.

Comment: I don't understand why it peaks at 150. I don't know how to anticipate this when automating signal processing.

Comment: You need to study how the DFT (FFT) is calculated, the peak is the first repetition of the negative frequency spectrum, if you have a peak in `f`, you will have one in `fs - f`. The second peak has the same magnitude as the 1st peak.